# Prerender.io not caching pages - followed all steps as per documentation

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate

We are trying to use pretender.io to our application which developed in AngularJS, Spring and Hibernate konnectnow.com which hosted at amazon server.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Signup at prerender.io and got token: `cFeRZcsv3JnAftreuhMO`
2. Checked documentation and understood that I need to install middleware and decided to use Spring one.
3. In web.xml added pom added as mentioned `https://github.com/greengerong/prerender-java`
4. Added `!#` to the URL in all the pages.
5. Restarted tomcat server.
6. Logged into pretender.io with login details and found that nothing getting crawl.
7. For testing purpose the url `konnectnow.com/#!/planpage` changed to `konnectnow.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/planpage`
8. Nothing comes up, got error page isn’t working.
9. Checked Crawl Stats at  pretender.io and found that as:

> Status Code: 505, Cache Hit: Miss, Response Time(sec): 1.51sec, URL:
>   http://localhost:8080/#!/planpage

10. Not sure why it takes local host.

Can some one help me how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

We recommend using html5 push state instead of the #! in your URLs if possible. Html5 push state is better since nothing after a # is sent to the server, which can lead to issues for the crawlers that are checked by their user agent (Facebook, Twitter, etc).

You should set the `forwardedURLHeader` in order to have the Prerender Java middleware use a different host for your website instead of your proxy URL.

https://github.com/greengerong/prerender-java#forwardedurlheader

I also see that you posted your prerender token publicly so we regenerated your token to prevent someone else from using it. Please find your new token when you log into your Prerender.io account. I've also emailed you there.